# Replies from Yahoo Mail sent from Samsung showing up in gmail account

Tags: samsung, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-8, yahoo-mail

For some reason, when I send an email from my Yahoo account from my Samsung 8+, the replies come into my Gmail account. When you look at the email reply, it clearly says "mailto:myyahooaddress" yet it only shows up in my gmail account.

I tested it by sending a friend an email and sure enough, when they do a reply, my Gmail address shows up even though it is sent from the Yahoo account.

I checked my settings in Yahoo and no where does it show my Gmail info other than recovery account did my email address show up. I deleted it and it still does the same thing.

Why is this happening and how to stop it? I am guessing it is a setting in the Samsung phone that is causing this.

Comment: Did you sign up for google account using your yahoo account?

Comment: Does the same happen when using a computer browser to check your email?

Comment: @Rajat - No I did not

Comment: @aBochur  I did do that and it works fine.  The reply goes back to my yahoo account. And there is no difference in the emails sent from either Samsung phone or computer.  The email headers look the same but when you hit reply, one goes back to the yahoo account (computer sent email) and one goes back to my gmail account (phone sent email).  It is very strange.

Comment: I have a feeling that it may be the recovery account, try changing the recovery account email to nothing or something else to see if the problem has anything to do with that.

Comment: @Zillinium I did that.  Same thing happened.

Comment: Well, I have narrowed the problem down to the embedded reply to address. For some reason, the emails sent from my Yahooo account from my phone shows up as my gmail account and I can't find where in the settings you can change it.  On my computer Yahoo client, there is an option and it clearly says to reply to the same address.

Anyone know who to find this setting on my phone?

Comment: Are you using any type of application to access your Yahoo or are you using Chrome ?... It's just that according to the information on the Yahoo7 App ( "
- SIGN UP WITH ANY ACCOUNT – works with non-Yahoo7 email addresses, including Gmail, Outlook and AOL. No Yahoo email address required."  )  You probably need to sign out and sign into your Yahoo email, Maybe you have logged in by pressing sign in with Google or something like that ? .. I'll try to reproduce this problem on my Yahoo to see if theirs an answer.

Comment: @Zillinium  I access Yahoo Mail via my Chrome browser on my computer.  On my phone i use the Yahoo Mail app.  The problem is email from my phone, ergo, the Yahoo Mail app.

The Yahoo Mail is the culprit as there is no way to set the REPLY TO as you can from their desktop app. And for some reason, the phone app is picking up my gmail address and using it as the reply to address instead of my Yahoo address.

I have seen other similar complaints online but no solutions.